# How do you reset a lost Facebook password?

Tags: facebook, account-recovery

***See edited info at the bottom.**

I've been trying to reset my Facebook password for the last months with no luck.

According to [this FAQ](https://www.facebook.com/help/213395615347144), you have to go [here](https://www.facebook.com/login/identify) to reset a lost password.

The first wrong thing is that, in that page, both "Find Your Account Page" and "recover your account" sent you to the same link:

[image: FAQ page]

The sencond wrong thing is that when you follow that link (that link is even used here to answer this problem) it asks you to write your phone or email.

After you enter your email, it only gives you two options **that are not related to password reset**!

- Enter Password to Log In
- I cannot Access My Email

The first one drives me nuts: I'm here because I don't know my password!

The second one is even more useless: It assumes that you don't have access to your email and just tells you that there is nothing you can do about it.

You can try the process by your own or see a video I've made: [link to the video (51 seconds)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1boy8-Y0xZOHBq6XBHtgMDOMeT9KpfrtF/view?usp=sharing)

I've post the same question several times in facebook "help" community but they keep sending me to the same FAQ page. Please, don't do the same unless I'm doing something wrong.

By the way, I'm spanish and tried the process in both languages several times this year.

Thank you.

---

**EDIT:** I've found that this problem is only on certain accounts. If I use my main one, The same link gives me other options:

[image: successful try]

Has anyone faced this problem? Any ideas why or how can I recover my lost account?